# Update 3.5.15.1 - Fixed a bug where the Updates utility wasn’t showing “Update” buttons

Tags: url, updates, button

The update button is missing, and the fix is available, but impossible to initiate from the CP.

[image]

Before I embark on a manual update, I wondered **if there was a URL that I could use to trigger the update**? (What URL does the button normally run?|)

Cheers

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a URL, but you can do it from the command line by running either:

```
php craft update craft
```

Or

```
composer update craftcms/cms
```

You can see the issue for this here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7091

Comment: Cheers Brad! Very helpful

Comment: Hi Brad, I couldn't get this to work for the life of me until I 1. Updated Composer (I know, it's the little things that matter right), and 2. changed my .env "DB_Server" to 127.0.0.1.

I'm using MAMP Pro, which only works if "BD_Server=localhost", so for updating Craft using "php craft update craft" I needed to change the value to "localhost' temporarily.

(Next step is to get MAMP Pro working with 127.0.0.1)

Thanks again!